# Live video from GigE Cameras

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I have a problem with live video stream from 2 GigE cameras in QML. I tried it before with QLabels and QPixmap and it worked without any problem. The QML Labels don't have pixmap property to send images using signal slots.

Here is my Python code:

```
import sys
import os
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PySide2.QtCore import Slot, QThread, Signal, Qt, QObject
import cv2
from pypylon import pylon


tlFactory = pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance()
devices = tlFactory.EnumerateDevices()
if len(devices) == 0:
    raise pylon.RuntimeException("No camera present.")

cameras = pylon.InstantCameraArray(min(len(devices), 2))


for i, cam in enumerate(cameras):
    cam.Attach(tlFactory.CreateDevice(devices[i]))


class CamThread(QThread):
    cam1 = Signal(QImage)
    cam2 = Signal(QImage)

    def run(self):
        cameras.StartGrabbing(pylon.GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly)

        try:

            while cameras.IsGrabbing():
                grabResult1 = cameras[0].RetrieveResult(
                    5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException
                )
                grabResult2 = cameras[1].RetrieveResult(
                    5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException
                )

                if grabResult1.GrabSucceeded() and grabResult2.GrabSucceeded():
                    img1 = grabResult1.GetArray()
                    img2 = grabResult2.GetArray()
                    rgb1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_YUV2RGB_Y422)
                    rgb2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_YUV2RGB_Y422)

                    h1, w1, ch1 = rgb1.shape
                    h2, w2, ch2 = rgb2.shape

                    bytesPerLine1 = ch1 * w1
                    bytesPerLine2 = ch2 * w1
                    convertToQtFormat1 = QImage(
                        img1.data, w1, h1, bytesPerLine1, QImage.Format_RGB888
                    )
                    convertToQtFormat2 = QImage(
                        img2.data, w2, h2, bytesPerLine2, QImage.Format_RGB888
                    )

                    p = convertToQtFormat1.scaled(800, 746, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                    q = convertToQtFormat2.scaled(800, 746, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

                    self.cam1.emit(p)
                    self.cam2.emit(q)

        except Exception as error:
            print(error)


class MainWindow(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.CamThread = CamThread()
        self.CamThread.cam1.connect(self.camera1)
        self.CamThread.cam2.connect(self.camera2)
        self.CamThread.start()

    @Slot(QImage)
    def camera1(self, image):
        pass

    @Slot(QImage)
    def camera2(self, image):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    backend = MainWindow()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", backend)
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So how to show live video stream using QML/PySide2?
I am using QT Design Studio.

Comment: I don't know how it'd work in Python, but usually you'd use [QQuickImageProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html#details) for this sort of stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is a solution in your case, but [`VideoOutput`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html) may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the QQuickImageProvider option can be a good one but the drawback is that you have to generate different urls, instead a better option is to use VideoOutput, for example in your case the following implementation should work (not tested):

```py
from functools import cached_property
import os
import random
import sys
import threading

import cv2

from PySide2.QtCore import Property, QObject, Qt, QSize, QTimer, Signal, Slot
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QGuiApplication, QImage
from PySide2.QtMultimedia import QAbstractVideoSurface, QVideoFrame, QVideoSurfaceFormat
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
import shiboken2

from pypylon import pylon


class CameraProvider(QObject):
    imageChanged = Signal(int, QImage)

    def start(self, cameras):
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, args=(cameras,), daemon=True).start()

    def _execute(self, cameras):
        while cameras.IsGrabbing():
            for i, camera in enumerate(cameras):
                try:
                    grab_result = cameras[i].RetrieveResult(
                        5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException
                    )
                    if grab_result.GrabSucceeded():
                        img = grab_result.GetArray()
                        # FIXME
                        # convert img to qimage
                        qimage = QImage(800, 746, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                        qimage.fill(QColor(*random.sample(range(0, 255), 3)))
                        if shiboken2.isValid(self):
                            self.imageChanged.emit(i, qimage.copy())
                except Exception as error:
                    print(error)


class CameraService(QObject):
    surfaceChanged = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._surface = None
        self._format = QVideoSurfaceFormat()
        self._format_is_valid = False

    def get_surface(self):
        return self._surface

    def set_surface(self, surface):
        if self._surface is surface:
            return
        if (
            self._surface is not None
            and self._surface is not surface
            and self._surface.isActive()
        ):
            self._surface.stop()
        self._surface = surface
        self.surfaceChanged.emit()

        if self._surface is not None:
            self._format = self._surface.nearestFormat(self._format)
            self._surface.start(self._format)

    videoSurface = Property(
        QAbstractVideoSurface,
        fget=get_surface,
        fset=set_surface,
        notify=surfaceChanged,
    )

    @Slot(QImage)
    def update_frame(self, qimage):
        if self.videoSurface is None or qimage.isNull():
            return
        if not self._format_is_valid:
            self._set_format(qimage.width(), qimage.height(), QVideoFrame.Format_RGB32)
            self._format_is_valid = True
        qimage.convertTo(
            QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(QVideoFrame.Format_RGB32)
        )
        self._surface.present(QVideoFrame(qimage))

    def _set_format(self, width, height, pixel_format):
        size = QSize(width, height)
        video_format = QVideoSurfaceFormat(size, pixel_format)
        self._format = video_format
        if self._surface is not None:
            if self._surface.isActive():
                self._surface.stop()
            self._format = self._surface.nearestFormat(self._format)
            self._surface.start(self._format)


class CameraManager(QObject):
    def __init__(self, cameras, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._services = []
        self.provider.imageChanged.connect(self.handle_image_changed)
        self.provider.start(cameras)
        for _ in cameras:
            self._services.append(CameraService())

    @cached_property
    def provider(self):
        return CameraProvider()

    @Slot(int, QImage)
    def handle_image_changed(self, index, qimage):
        self._services[index].update_frame(qimage)

    def get_services(self):
        return self._services

    services = Property("QVariantList", fget=get_services, constant=True)


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    tlFactory = pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance()
    devices = tlFactory.EnumerateDevices()
    if len(devices) == 0:
        raise pylon.RuntimeException("No camera present.")

    cameras = pylon.InstantCameraArray(min(len(devices), 2))

    for i, cam in enumerate(cameras):
        cam.Attach(tlFactory.CreateDevice(devices[i]))

    manager = CameraManager(cameras)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("manager", manager)
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtMultimedia 5.14

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    GridView {
        width: 300; height: 200

        model: manager !== null ? manager.services : []
        delegate: VideoOutput {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectCrop
            source: model.modelData
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, the window closes after 2 seconds without any  errors and warnings?

Comment: @user31562 I don't have a way to test the code since I don't have the HW. I have been testing creating QImage with random colors and they work correctly so I recommend you check the conversion logic that I have not modified anything, I also recommend running the script from the console since that way you probably have more information about the error

Comment: Thank you, It worked with some changes in image converting. When I test one camera it's ok but with two cameras the frame rate drop and videos become slow. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Qt provides different methods to pass images/video streams to QML:

### 1. Converting pixmap to base64 encoding

```
QByteArray byteArray;
QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
pixmap.save(&buffer,"PNG");
QString data("data:image/png;base64,");
data.append(QString::fromLatin1(byteArray.toBase64().data()));
```

This base64 encoded image may be passed to [`Image::source`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#source-prop)

### 2. Use [`QQuickImageProvider`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html#details)

This allows connecting a custom `image://...` url to a `QPixmap` or `QImage` directly. Check the docs for more information.

### 3. Use [`QtMultimedia`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-index.html)

Especially [`VideoOutput`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html) may be useful.